# Recursively search directory for occurrences of each string from one column of a .csv file

Tags: awk, replace, grep

I have a CSV file--let's call it `search.csv`--with three columns. For each row, the first column contains a different string. As an example (punctuation of the strings is intentional):

```
Col 1,Col 2,Col 3
string1,valueA,stringAlpha
string 2,valueB,stringBeta
string'3,valueC,stringGamma
```

I also have a set of directories contained within one overarching parent directory, each of which have a subdirectory we'll call `source`, such that the path to `source` would look like this: `~/parentDirectory/directoryA/source`

What I would like to do is search the `source` subdirectories for any occurrences--in **any** file--of each of the strings in `Col 1` of `search.csv`. Some of these strings will need to be manually edited, while others can be categorically replaced. I run the following command . . .

```
awk -F "," '{print $1}' search.csv | xargs -I@ grep -Frli @ ~/parentDirectory/*/source/*
```

What I would want is a list of files that match the criteria described above.

My `awk` call gets a few hits, followed by `xargs: unterminated quote`. There are some single quotes in some of the strings in the first column that I suspect may be the problem. The larger issue, however, is that when I did a sanity check on the results I got (which seemed far too few to be right), there was a vast discrepancy. I ran the following:

`ag -l "searchTerm" ~/parentDirectory`

Where `searchTerm` is a substring of many (but not all) of the strings in the first column of `search.csv`. In contrast to my above `awk`-based approach which returned 11 files before throwing an error, `ag` found 154 files containing that particular substring.

Additionally, my current approach is too low-resolution even if it didn't error out, in that it wouldn't distinguish between which results are for which strings, which would be key to selectively auto-replacing certain strings. Am I mistaken in thinking this should be doable entirely in `awk`? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a sample input file which contains the target strings as well as each result of `ag` and your `awk` based approach so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: You say you have a CSV and your code sets `FS` to `,` but there's no `,`s in the sample input you provided. Please fix that and add the missing expected output.